# regular expression

Tags: regular-expression

I'm not sure about the meaning of this regular expression.

```
^[^a]*$
```

Does that mean, we don't want any string started with the letter a or contain a. And we don't want any string ended with also the letter a ?.

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `^` asserts position at start of a line
- `[^a]` Match a single character not present in the list
- `*` Quantifier — Matches between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
- `$` asserts position at the end of a line

So it will essentially match any line and *does not* contain an `a`